# how do I find the values of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: calculus

it says that $x^a - y^a = b$ is a curve, $y=2x-3$ is its tangent line and $2y=4-x$ is perpendicular to the tangent line and I need to find what $a+2b$ equals. How can I do that? do I find the point where the tangent line and the perpendicular intersect? but what do I do after that?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, find the intersection point which is (2, 1). 
the key point is (2, 1) is on the curve and $\frac{dy}{dx} |_{(x=2, y=1)} = 2$ since value k of tangent line is 2 
to get $\frac{dy}{dx}$, see $y = y(x)$ and from
$$x^a - y^a = b$$
$$ax^{a-1} - ay^{a-1} \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = (\frac{x}{y})^{a-1}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} |_{(2, 1)} = 2^{a-1}$$
hence
$$\frac{dy}{dx} |_{(2, 1)} = 2^{a-1} = 2$$
$$a = 2$$
use another condition: (2, 1) is on the curve, which means
$$2^a - 1^a = b$$
$$b = 2^a - 1 = 3$$
hence
$$a + 2b = 8$$